# How to get access to query parameter in node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I write simple pagination module for my express app. Here is the code:

```
var config = require('../config');

function Pagination(options) {
    this.param  = options.param || 'page';
    //this.current = ?
    this.perPage = options.perPage || config.perPage;
    this.numPages = Math.ceil(options.numRows / this.perPage);
    this.prevPage = null;
    this.nextPage = null;
    this.hasPrevPage = function() {
        return (this.current > 1 && this.numPages);
    }
    this.hasNextPage = function() {
        return (this.numPages > this.current);
    }

    if (this.hasPrevPage()) {
        this.prevPage = this.current - 1;
    }

    if (this.hasNextPage()) {
        this.nextPage = this.current + 1;
    }
}

module.exports = Pagination;
```

One of *options* properties is *param*. It is the name of get request parameter and by default it is "page". For example when the route is:

```
/posts/?page=3
```

*pagination.current* sets to 3

I assume using this module in my app should look like this

app.js:

```
//...
var postsRoute = require('./routes/posts');
app.use('/posts', postsRoute);
```

(/routes/posts.js):

```
var express       = require('express');
var Pagination    = require('..core/pagination');
var config        = require('../config');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //...
    pagination = new Pagination({
        numRows: dbresult.count,
        perPage: config.perPage
    });

    res.render('posts', {posts: dbresult.rows, pagination: pagination});
});
```

So if module knows what is the name of the pagination parameter it should be able to get it's value. How to do it right inside module, not inside every route? Using only basic node functionality is desirable.

Comment: You don't show the actual starting of your express server and hooking the router into that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Edited. But I don't think it's really needed. I want to get access from any request, not single route. For example in php we have $_REQUEST array available everywhere. I ask for something like this for node.js, not single express route or even express framework.

Answer (score 1):

Use `req.query.page` to get the 3.  In other words,

```
router.get('/posts', function(req, res) {
    var page = req.query.page   // = 3
```

Comment: I know how to get request parameter inside the route. I want to get it right inside my module, for any route.

Comment: @femalemoustache- a request parameter is ONLY valid within a given request.  It doesn't exist outside the specific request.  PHP works differently.